# DataTables Responsive Child rows don't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

Responsive Datatable with child rows works on DataTables own page example, but the same code dosen't work on my HTML page. No '+' button shows and all the child columns are included in the main table. I have tried using all the examples but getting the same result.

[table without expand/collapse icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjNd0.png)

[I'm using this example for this question](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/child-rows/whole-row-control.html)

```
<html>

<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.1/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.1/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" class="init">

     $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable( {
            responsive: {
                details: {
                    type: 'column',
                    target: 'tr'
                }
            },
            columnDefs: [ {
                className: 'control',
                orderable: false,
                targets:   0
            } ],
            order: [ 1, 'asc' ]
        } );
    } );

    </script>

</head>

<body>

    <table id="example" class="display nowrap" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>First name</th>
                <th>Last name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
                <th>Extn.</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Tiger</td>
                <td>Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
                <td>5421</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Garrett</td>
                <td>Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
                <td>8422</td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>First name</th>
                <th>Last name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
                <th>Extn.</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Also, copying the whole source of the example page in local html gives the same result. But the example in the page itself i.e. by opening page as link in datatables site works in chrome.

Comment: Even its working fine in my codepen. https://codepen.io/smitraval27/pen/MVoQXP

Comment: Check if all js and css are including properly?

Comment: The table shows but the Responsive child rows don't. See the example in link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as I said in the [forum](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/127842/#Comment_127842), it does work - have you tried resizing the screen? Bear in mind you only see the child rows when the screen has shrunk enough that the whole line cannot be displayed.